# How to correctly write SQL metacode in metaprogramming?

Tags: sql, metaprogramming, dolphindb

Here is my script:

```
snap = loadTable("dfs://China_Market_HF", `Market_Snapshot)
select count(*) from snap where Date = 2015.01.15
exec(<select count(*) from snap where Date = 2015.01.15>)
```

In this script, the SQL statement

```
select count(*) 
from table 
where d == 2023.10.10
```

is correct, but I get an error:

> Syntax Error: [line #3] FROM clause expected

Comment: Your 2nd snippet doesn't match your first snippet. Please make sure you provide the correct code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In metaprogramming, you should use the eval function to evaluate the given metacode, instead of `exec`.

```
eval(<select count(*) from table where d == 2023.10.10>)
```